# How to find length of dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am pretty new to all of this so this might be a noobie question.. but I am looking to find length of dictionary values... but I do not know how this can be done.

So for example,

```
d = {'key':['hello', 'brave', 'morning', 'sunset', 'metaphysics']}
```

I was wondering is there a way I can find the **len** or **number of items** of the dictionary value.

Thanks

Comment: as discussed below, it does matter what you will be doing with your lengths...length for each key or just a list of lengths?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Sure.  In this case, you'd just do:

```
length_key = len(d['key'])  # length of the list stored at `'key'` ...
```

It's hard to say why you actually want this, but, perhaps it would be useful to create another dict that maps the keys to the length of values:

```
length_dict = {key: len(value) for key, value in d.items()}
length_key = length_dict['key']  # length of the list stored at `'key'` ...
```

Comment: +1, but "length_key" is a bit misleading as a variable name given that it's the length of the value that is being given.

Comment: @user1269942 -- Yeah, I was having a hard time coming up with a good name for that one. . .

Comment: @mgilson I'd go with `foo` and `bar` :)

Comment: @mgilson, I can give a reason why this would be helpful. Say you have a dictionary of lists that all have the same length but you do not now the keys just as yet and you want to loop over the list values first and then the keys. In this case you would have to do a 
`n = len(list(dict.items())[0])`
and then loop over list values

Answer (score 17):

Lets do some experimentation, to see how we could get/interpret the length of different dict/array values in a dict.

create our test dict, see [list and dict comprehensions](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html):

```
>>> my_dict = {x:[i for i in range(x)] for x in range(4)}
>>> my_dict
{0: [], 1: [0], 2: [0, 1], 3: [0, 1, 2]}
```

Get the length of the value of a specific key:

```
>>> my_dict[3]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> len(my_dict[3])
3
```

Get a dict of the lengths of the values of each key:

```
>>> key_to_value_lengths = {k:len(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
>>> key_to_value_lengths[2]
2
```

Get the sum of the lengths of all values in the dict:

```
>>> [len(x) for x in my_dict.values()]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> sum([len(x) for x in my_dict.values()])
6
```

Answer (score 11):

To find all of the lengths of the values in a dictionary you can do this:

```
lengths = [len(v) for v in d.values()]
```

Comment: @squinguy I think because a dict does not preserve order doing it this way would be ambiguous in terms of which list item corresponds to which dict entry.

Comment: @user1269942 That's fair, although there was no mention of correlating the values to their keys. I took it as just seeing the lengths of all the values.

Comment: ya, a fair interpretation!  I hadn't thought of that...I just added a comment letting them know there's ambiguity.

Answer (score 7):

A common use case I have is a dictionary of numpy arrays or lists where I know they're all the same length, and I just need to know one of them (e.g. I'm plotting timeseries data and each timeseries has the same number of timesteps). I often use this:

```
length = len(next(iter(d.values())))
```

Comment: Great solution. But hard to understand how it works. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @lpnorm it's easiest to follow from inside out: `iter(d.values())` creates an iterator object over the dictionary's values, `next` retrieves the first object from the iterator, and `len` tells you how many elements are in that retrieved object.

Answer (score 1):

Let dictionary be : 
 `dict={'key':['value1','value2']}`
If you know the key :
 `print(len(dict[key]))`
else : 
`val=[len(i) for i in dict.values()]`
 `print(val[0])`
 `# for printing length of 1st key value or length of values in keys if all keys have same amount of values.`

Comment: You should use 'key' instead of key otherwise it gives you `NameError: name 'key' is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

```
d={1:'a',2:'b'}
sum=0
for i in range(0,len(d),1):
   sum=sum+1
i=i+1
print i
```

OUTPUT=2

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.