# keeping dictionary values greater than length of five

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, loops, dictionary

```
d = {'key1':['hello', 'ab', 'a', 'morning', 'sunset', 'metaphysics'],
     'key2':['hi', 'morning', 'sunset', 'metaphysics'], 
     'key3':['hey', 'sunset', 'metaphysics']}
```

I have a dict `d` and I want to keep only those elements of length 5 or greater. So I want my output to be

```
d = {'key1':['hello', 'morning', 'sunset', 'metaphysics'],
     'key2':['morning', 'sunset', 'metaphysics'], 
     'key3':['sunset', 'metaphysics']}
```

I looked here [How to find length of dictionary values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190160/how-to-find-length-of-dictionary-values) but this does help much.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {'key1':['hello', 'ab', 'a', 'morning', 'sunset', 'metaphysics'],
     'key2':['hi', 'morning', 'sunset', 'metaphysics'],
     'key3':['hey', 'sunset', 'metaphysics']}

for key, val in d.items():
    d[key] = [v for v in val if len(v) > 4]

print (d)
```

{'key1': ['hello', 'morning', 'sunset', 'metaphysics'], 'key2': ['morning', 'sunset', 'metaphysics'], 'key3': ['sunset', 'metaphysics']}

Answer (score 0):

using only comprehension.

```
    d = {'key1':['hello', 'ab', 'a', 'morning', 'sunset', 'metaphysics'],
         'key2':['hi', 'morning', 'sunset', 'metaphysics'],
         'key3':['hey', 'sunset', 'metaphysics']}

    d  = {key: [v for v in value if len(v) >4] for key, value in d.items()}
    print(d)
```

{'key1': ['hello', 'morning', 'sunset', 'metaphysics'], 'key2': ['morning', 'sunset', 'metaphysics'], 'key3': ['sunset', 'metaphysics']}

Comment: how is this different from other answer?

Comment: The output is the same, only thing is it uses comprehension.