# skip short letter/word mix in dictionary

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, list, dictionary

```
d = {'E1': ['Fish','1B', '12C35','53901','AB3', '11Rs', 'C140','funny', '2ml', '5mm', '1a'],
       'E2': ['Jon','521','ag14', 'O2', 'Sp02', 'fun', '1245A444', 'BAK1', 'TA42']}
```

I have the following dictionary `d`. I want to not keep **letter/number mix** 4 characters or shorter e.g. `'1B'` or  `AB3'` or `'C140'` etc will all be skipped. I would like the following output:

```
d = {'E1': ['Fish','12C35','53901', 'funny'],
       'E2': ['Jon','521', 'fun', '1245A444']}
```

To get the output I want above, I'm not sure if regex would be the answer or something like this [keeping dictionary values greater than length of five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57797768/keeping-dictionary-values-greater-than-length-of-five) (but this doesnt give me the output I want). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-construct the dict with a dict comprehension where you filter the lists using the following condition:

```
d = {k : list(filter(lambda s : len(s) > 4 or s.isdigit() or not any(c.isdigit() for c in s), v)) for k, v in d.items()}

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'E1': ['Fish', '12C35', '53901', 'funny'], 'E2': ['Jon', '521', 'fun', '1245A444BAK1']}
```

Alternatively, using a list comprehension instead of `filter` + `lambda`:

```
d = {k : [s for s in v if len(s) > 4 or s.isdigit() or not any(c.isdigit() for c in s)] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: this is also close but `O2` should not be kept

Comment: @510 `02` is not a numbers/letters mix, so based on what condition should it be kept?

Comment: `O2` letter `O` and number `2`

Comment: sorry that was my mistake for the typo on my original post

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code:

```
>>> dd={}
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...     dd[k] = [x for x in v if re.search(r'^(?:\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)$', x) or len(x) > 4]
...
>>> print (dd)
{'E1': ['Fish', '12C35', '53901', 'funny'], 'E2': ['Jon', '521', 'fun', '1245A444BAK1']}
```

This code iterates over original dictionary and stores values in a new dictionary if any of the 2 conditions are satisfied for each value:

1. Comprises of only digits or only alphabets.
2. Length is greater than 4.

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/a3EOiR)

Comment: this is close but `O2` should not be kept

Comment: I think your typo of `O2` instead of `02` caused this mistake in my answer (fixed now)

Answer (score 1):

you could use `regex`:

```
import re

{key:re.findall(r'(?m)^(\d+|[\D+|\w{5,})$','\n'.join(val)) for key,val in d.items()}
```

Gives:

```
{'E1': ['Fish', '12C35', '53901', 'funny'],
 'E2': ['Jon', '521', 'fun', '1245A444BAK1']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following data:

```py
d = {'E1': ['Fish','1B', '12C35','53901','AB3', '11Rs', 'C140','funny', '2ml', '5mm', '1a'],
       'E2': ['Jon','521','ag14', 'O2', 'Sp02', 'fun', '1245A444' 'BAK1', 'TA42']}
```

- Condition: **I want to not keep letter/word mix 4 characters or shorter**
- Without `re`

```py
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = [x for x in v if (x.isalnum() and len(x) > 4) | x.isalpha() | x.isnumeric()]
```

#### Output:

```py
{'E1': ['Fish', '12C35', '53901', 'funny'],
 'E2': ['Jon', '521', 'fun', '1245A444BAK1']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a test-function and alter your dictionary:

```
def valid(t):
    """True for all things longer then 4 chars, True for all things shorter that
    only consist of letters or digits, False else"""
    if len(t) > 4:
        return True
    return all(str.isdigit(k) for k in t) or all(str.isalpha(k) for k in t)

d = {'E1': ['Fish','1B', '12C35','53901','AB3', '11Rs', 'C140','funny', '2ml', '5mm', '1a'],
     'E2': ['Jon','521','ag14', '02', 'Sp02', 'fun', '1245A444' 'BAK1', 'TA42']}


# modify the dict
for k in d: 
    d[k] = [d for d in d[k] if valid(d)]

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'E1': ['Fish', '12C35', '53901', 'funny'], 
 'E2': ['Jon', '521', '02', 'fun', '1245A444BAK1']}
```

Your "wanted" solution for `'E2'` omits `'02'` which only consists of numbers and should be kept. You edited your post later to change `'02'` to `'O2'` - which would be removed by this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict comprehension with a nested list comprehension that iterates over the words in the sub-list and outputs the word if the word is either all alphabets or all digits, or if the word is greater than 4 in length:

```
{k: [w for w in l if any(all(map(f, w)) for f in (str.isalpha, str.isdigit)) or len(w) > 4] for k, l in d.items()}
```

which returns:

```
{'E1': ['Fish', '12C35', '53901', 'funny'], 'E2': ['Jon', '521', 'fun', '1245A444']}
```